# Database connection leak

Tags: java, jdbc

Recently, I had to measure the time taken by some of the SQL requests of our software. To do that, I decided to take the naive approach and surround queries with calls to System.nanoTime().
While doing that I found a class (SqlSuggest) containing 4 very similar queries in 4 very similar methods. I thought it would be a good idea to refactor and regroup the common parts.

This created a connection leak, the connections weren't closed anymore. I rolled back the refactor but I'd still like to understand what I did wrong.

The first version of the SqlSuggest class has 4 methods getSuggestListByItems, getDisplayValueByItems, getSuggestListByListID and getDisplayValueByListeID. Each of these methods opens and closes a Connection, Statement and ResultSet (in a finally block) through another class: DBAccess.

The second version of that class has the same 4 methods except instead of opening and closing the Connection, they call 1 of 2 methods depending on whether they need one result or a list.

Those 2 methods (executeQueryGetString and executeQueryGetListOfStringArray) each declare the Connection, Statement and ResultSet, then call a method: executeQuery where the Connection is open, the Statement is created and the ResultSet returned.

The second-tier method then extracts the data from the ResultSet and closes everything.

I'm guessing I was wrong in thinking that declaring the Connection, Statement and ResultSet in a method would then allow me to close them from the same method.

Here is the old class (simplified):

```
public class SqlSuggest {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();

    public List<String[]> getSuggestListByItems(String codeSite) {
        List<String[]> suggestList = new ArrayList<>();
        String query = "SELECT iDcode, designation FROM Mytable WHERE codeSite = " + codeSite; // Simplified query building
        DBAccess accesBD = new DBAccess();
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            conn = accesBD.getConnection();
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()) {
                suggestList.add(new String[]{rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2)});
            }
        } catch (NamingException | SQLException ex) {
            LOGGER.error("", ex);
        } finally {
            accesBD.closeResultSet(rs);
            accesBD.closeStatement(stmt);
            accesBD.closeConnection(conn);
        }
        return suggestList;
    }

    public String getDisplayValueByItems(String table, String codeSite) {
        String displayValue = null;
        String query = "SELECT iDcode, designation FROM " + table + " WHERE codeSite = " + codeSite; // Different query building
        DBAccess accesBD = new DBAccess();
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            conn = accesBD.getConnection();
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            if (rs.next()) {
                displayValue = rs.getString(1);
            }
        } catch (NamingException | SQLException ex) {
            LOGGER.error("", ex);

        } finally {
            accesBD.closeResultSet(rs);
            accesBD.closeStatement(stmt);
            accesBD.closeConnection(conn);
        }

        return displayValue;
    }

    public List<String[]> getSuggestListByListID(String listeID, String table, String codeSite) {
        List<String[]> suggestList = new ArrayList<>();
        String query = "SELECT iDcode, designation FROM " + table + " WHERE codeSite = " + codeSite; // Different query building involving listID
        DBAccess accesBD = new DBAccess();
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            conn = accesBD.getConnection();

            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()) {
                suggestList.add(new String[]{rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2)});
            }
        } catch (NamingException | SQLException ex) {
            LOGGER.error("", ex);
        } finally {
            accesBD.closeResultSet(rs);
            accesBD.closeStatement(stmt);
            accesBD.closeConnection(conn);
        }
        return suggestList;
    }

    public String getDisplayValueByListeID(String listeID, String table, String codeSite) {
        String displayValue = null;        
        String query = "SELECT iDcode, designation FROM " + table + " WHERE codeSite = " + codeSite; // Different query building involving listID
        DBAccess accesBD = new DBAccess();
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            conn = accesBD.getConnection();
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            if (rs.next()) {
                displayValue = rs.getString(2);
            }
        } catch (NamingException | SQLException ex) {
            LOGGER.error("", ex);
        } finally {
            accesBD.closeResultSet(rs);
            accesBD.closeStatement(stmt);
            accesBD.closeConnection(conn);
        }


        return displayValue;
    }
}
```

Here is the new class (the one with the leak):

```
public class SqlSuggest {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();

    public List<String[]> getSuggestListByItems(String codeSite) {
        List<String[]> suggestList;
        String query = "SELECT iDcode, designation FROM Mytable WHERE codeSite = " + codeSite; // Simplified query building
        suggestList = executeQueryGetListOfStringArray(query);
        return suggestList;
    }

    public String getDisplayValueByItems(String table, String codeSite) {
        String displayValue = null;
        String query = "SELECT iDcode, designation FROM " + table + " WHERE codeSite = " + codeSite; // Different query building
        int columnToFetch = 1;
        displayValue = executeQueryGetString(query, columnToFetch);
        return displayValue;
    }

    public List<String[]> getSuggestListByListID(String listeID, String table, String codeSite) {
        List<String[]> suggestList = new ArrayList<>();
        String query = "SELECT iDcode, designation FROM " + table + " WHERE codeSite = " + codeSite; // Different query building involving listID
        suggestList = executeQueryGetListOfStringArray(query);
        return suggestList;
    }

    public String getDisplayValueByListeID(String listeID, String table, String codeSite) {
        String displayValue = null;
        String query = "SELECT iDcode, designation FROM " + table + " WHERE codeSite = " + codeSite; // Different query building involving listID
        int columnToFetch = 2;
        displayValue = executeQueryGetString(query, columnToFetch);
        return displayValue;
    }

    private String executeQueryGetString(String query, int columnToFetch){
        String result = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        ResultSet rs = executeQuery(query, stmt, conn);
        try{
            if (rs.next()) {
                result = rs.getString(columnToFetch);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            LOGGER.error("", ex);
        } finally {
            DBAccess accesBD = new DBAccess();
            accesBD.closeResultSet(rs);
            accesBD.closeStatement(stmt);
            accesBD.closeConnection(conn);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private List<String[]> executeQueryGetListOfStringArray(String query){
        List<String[]> result = new ArrayList<>();
        Statement stmt = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        ResultSet rs = executeQuery(query, stmt, conn);
        try{
            while (rs.next()) {
                result.add(new String[]{rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2)});
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            LOGGER.error("", ex);
        } finally {
            DBAccess accesBD = new DBAccess();
            accesBD.closeResultSet(rs);
            accesBD.closeStatement(stmt);
            accesBD.closeConnection(conn);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private ResultSet executeQuery(String query, Statement stmt, Connection conn){
        DBAccess accesBD = new DBAccess();
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            conn = accesBD.getConnection();
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);   
        } catch (NamingException | SQLException ex) {
            LOGGER.error("", ex);
        }
        return rs;
    }
}
```

And here is the class that actually opens and closes the connections (which wasn't changed in any way):

```
    public class DBAccess {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();

    public void closeResultSet(ResultSet rs) {
        if (rs != null) {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.error("", e);
            }
        }
    }

    public void closeStatement(Statement stmt) {
        if (stmt != null) {
            try {
                stmt.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.error("", e);
            }
        }
    }

    public void closeConnection(Connection conn) {
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.error("", e);
            }
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException, NamingException {
        Connection cnx = null;
        PropertiesManager manager = PropertiesDelegate.getPropertiesManager();
        String jndi = manager.getProperty("datasource.name", "QuartisWeb-PU");
        Context ctx = null;
        DataSource dataSource = null;
        try {
            ctx = new InitialContext();
            dataSource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup(jndi);
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            try {
                dataSource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/" + jndi);
            } catch (NamingException ex1) {
                LOGGER.error("", ex1);
            }
        }
        if (dataSource != null) {
            cnx = dataSource.getConnection();
        }
        return cnx;
    }

}
```

Please disregard the fact that those parameters aren't correctly set in the query, I know it should be done.

Comment: I would strongly recommend using an existing framework (perhaps Apache Commons Db that has methods like 'closeQuietly' closing your statement, connection and resultset in the right order), or SpringJdbc, which encapsulates a lot of the above

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm thinking for the next project. But this one is 10 years old, it's in production and we have more pressing matters than fixing what's working. Someday...

Comment: @BrianAgnew Or use try-with-resources, not exactly the same effect like `closeQuietly, but less clutter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you make a call from `executeQueryGetString()` to `executeQuery()` the value of `conn` and `stmt` will change inside `executeQuery()` but will remain `null` inside `executeQueryGetString()` upon return. Therefore, at the `finally` of `executeQueryGetString()` the call to `accesBD.closeConnection(conn)` is actually doing `accesBD.closeConnection(null)`